# All browsers are crashing using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, crash, selenium-chromedriver

Hi there I'm new to coding but especially to python/selenium et.c. so please bare with me.

I've been trying to develop a scrapper for Facebook for an art project by using Selenium. After some dabbling about and starting to actually experiment with the python code, installing chromedriver into the environments et.c. I started trying to access Facebook through the scrapper **when suddenly**---
all my browsers (but mostly Chrome) started crashing on any page with a general exception stating: **STATUS_ERROR_VIOLATION** (see attached pic for reference). Once it even blocked my whole internet access through a DNS fail (513 I think) and I had to flush the DNS.

I searched everywhere but nobody seems to have had this exact problem.
I deleted all chromedrivers, uninstalled them from the environments, updated Google Chrome a few times, uninstalled it and reinstalled it, restarted all processes and the computer multiple times but the problem persists.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am so frustrated because there is NO improvement whatsoever...

Snapshot of the error:

[image: I am a new user so I can only upload an imgur link]

Comment: What Chrome driver does is merely load a new instance of Chrome, seems more likely there's an error in your OS config (since you mention even another browser is crashing) that's unveiled by the Chrome instance. This question belongs to SuperUser since your error persist even without chromedriver.

Comment: Okay, so what do you recommend me doing? How should I go about flushing this out of my system. 

Also to update- now also programms crash, not only browsers- even photoviewers.

Is there something I can do besides reinstalling my windows?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) have recently added specific error codes to the ***Aw snap*** crash pages.

[image: STATUS_ERROR_VIOLATION]

The very first step in resilving this issue would be to ensure the following:

- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v97.0.4692.71](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=97.0.4692.71/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *chrome=97.0.4692.99* (as per [chrome=97.0.4692.71 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/97.0.4692.71/notes.txt)).

---

### Addressing STATUS_ERROR_VIOLATION

[STATUS_ERROR_VIOLATION](https://www.chromestory.com/2020/05/status_access_violation/) still doesn't have any definite fix available. However *Will B 7332* in a [comment](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/23146500/chrome-only-showing-an-aw-snap-error-and-i-can-t-figure-out-how-to-fix-it?hl=en&msgid=23212912) suggests the following steps:

- Locate the Chrome application. You will most likely find this in *`C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application`*.
- Rename the Chrome executable to anything other than Chrome. For example, *`chrm`*.
- Open Chrome again and test.

Additionally, review the extensions visiting *`chrome://extensions`* on a new tab and check all the installed extensions.

- If you have Tampermonkey extension installed, uninstall it. Restart Chrome and execute your again.
- If you find any other extensions that you no longer use, uninstall them as well.